# Does java spring config have the ability to resolve variables from custom variable resolvers?

Tags: java, spring, variables, configuration

In .net spring land you can declare a custom variable source and do `${variableName}` style variables in your spring config. You do it by implementing an interface (`IVariableSource`) and it looks like this:

```
<object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
    <property name="VariableSources">
        <list>
            <ref object="MyVariableSource" />
        </list>
    </property>
</object>

<object id="TestObject" type="TestProject.TestObject, TestProject" singleton="false">
    <constructor-arg type="string" value="${MyVariableDefinedInMyVariableSource}" />
</object>
```

What is the equivalent of this in java spring land?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same in `Java` too. Below is the example.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:config/config.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="myController"
    <property name="variableName" value="${variableName}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw the docs for PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, but it's not quite the same. I'm not reading the values from a property file but from a database